# What wattage cable will be used for this oven installation?

Tags: electrical

I was wondering if I bought an oven like [this](http://www.johnlewis.com/john-lewis-jlfsec612-induction-hob-electric-cooker-stainless-steel/p1129103?tmcampid=51&tmad=c&s_pccid=pc_pr_200_40000) what wattage cabling would I need to power it? I'm a complete novice at electrical engineering and trying to learn a thing or two. If watts = voltage * a, and I had this oven running at 240v and the oven requires 15kw (it says 12.9 but just to make it a bit simpler), the amperage comes out at 62.5, which is seemingly extremely high, as most of the cables I know of are about 16A

Comment: Wire is rated for current, not wattage. Cookers need a lot of power; in the USA, we'd use AWG8 wire for this circuit. In the EU, this would correspond to 3-3.5 mm diameter, or the old British SWG10.

Comment: In the UK house wiring is solid with amps on them such as this one: http://www.diy.com/departments/tower-white-pvc-cable-240v-16a-3-core-15mm-25m/189618_BQ.prd. Basically my question is if an oven needed 62.5A, how would I get that if a standard wire can only carry 16A? I'm guessing you have to connect multiple wires together in some form..

Comment: @user35460 You wouldn't use "standard" wire, you'd use thicker wire. Notice the cable you linked to has 1.5 mm wires, so it can handle 16 amperes.  If the wire was thicker; 3.5 mm for example, it would be able to handle higher currents.

Comment: I understand @DaveTweed's comment about AWG now, I remember using that before for a much smaller project actually. But why is that this site for example: http://www.4-max.co.uk/silicone-wire.htm lists 8AWG as being able to handle up to 180A but this site: http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm claims 8AWG wiring can only handle 73A.

Comment: You need [this cable](http://www.diy.com/departments/prysmian-100mm-twin-earth-cable-reel-l2m/177870_BQ.prd?icamp=recs) -- 10.0 mm^2, rated at 63A.